# WebGL perspective projection matrix not working

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

Trying to write basic WebGL program, which draws a triangle to the screen. Without any projection matrix it works just right, as well as with identity matrix. But when it comes to perspective projection matrix it just shows nothing. Here is my code:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("viewport");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");
gl.viewport(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

const vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
const fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

gl.shaderSource(vs, document.getElementById("vs").innerText);
gl.shaderSource(fs, document.getElementById("fs").innerText);

gl.compileShader(vs);
gl.compileShader(fs);

if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)){
    const info = gl.getShaderInfoLog(vs);
    throw new Error("Error compiling vertex shader:\n\n" + info);
}

if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)){
    const info = gl.getShaderInfoLog(fs);
    throw new Error("Error compiling fragment shader:\n\n" + info);
}

const program = gl.createProgram();

gl.attachShader(program, vs);
gl.attachShader(program, fs);

gl.linkProgram(program);
gl.validateProgram(program);

gl.useProgram(program);

const position = [
    -0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
     0.0,  0.5, 0.0,
     0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
];

const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(position), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

const projectionMatrix = [
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1,
];

const FOV = 70;
const NEAR_PLANE = .1;
const FAR_PLANE = 1000;

const aspectRatio = canvas.width / canvas.height;
const yScale = (1.0 / Math.tan((FOV / 2.0) * (Math.PI / 180.0))) * aspectRatio;
const xScale = yScale / aspectRatio;
const frustumLength = FAR_PLANE - NEAR_PLANE;

projectionMatrix[0] = xScale;
projectionMatrix[5] = yScale;
projectionMatrix[10] = ((FAR_PLANE + NEAR_PLANE) / frustumLength) * -1.0;
projectionMatrix[11] = -1.0;
projectionMatrix[14] = ((2.0 * NEAR_PLANE * FAR_PLANE) / frustumLength) * -1;
projectionMatrix[15] = 0;

gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_Projection"), false, projectionMatrix)

const loop = () => {
    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8);
    gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

loop();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script id="vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">#version 300 es
        precision highp float;
        precision highp int;

        layout(location=0) in vec3 a_Position;

        out vec4 v_Position;

        uniform mat4 u_Projection;

        void main()
        {
            gl_Position = u_Projection * vec4(a_Position, 1.0);
            v_Position = gl_Position;
        }
    </script>

    <script id="fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">#version 300 es
        precision highp float;
        precision highp int;

        in vec4 v_Position;

        out vec4 out_Color;

        void main()
        {
            out_Color = v_Position;
        }
    </script>
    <canvas id="viewport"></canvas>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30429728/13450959) solution, but id didn`t work either.

Comment: silly thought: try `out_Color = vec4(v_Position.xy, 1.0, 1.0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried moving the triangle back a bit?  Based on your `NEAR_PLAIN`, the triangle is too close.  Try:

```
    const position = [
        -0.5, -0.5, -1.0,
         0.0,  0.5, -1.0,
         0.5, -0.5, -1.0,
    ];
```

Just as an aside, I'm not sure I agree with the math that you're using to create your projection matrix.  I think it would be worth comparing against https://glmatrix.net/docs/mat4.js.html#line1508, which I believe gives a different result.

Comment: gosh, I knew I was missing something obvious. This works, thank you

Comment: You bet, glad to help.